# What's the intended pattern of canceling already running CompletableFutures

Tags: java, completable-future

I couldn't find any information in "Java 8 in Action" on why `CompletableFuture` purposefully ignores `mayInterruptIfRunning`. But even if so, I don't really see any hook for custom `cancel(boolean)`, which would come in handy in cases, where interruption doesn't affect a blocking operation (such as I/O streams, simple locks, and so on). So far it seems that tasks themselves are the intended hooks and working on the abstraction level of `Future` simply won't do any good here.

Therefore I'm asking about the minimum set of boilerplate code one has to introduce to squeeze some neet custom cancellation mechanism out of this situation.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent

Comment: "Maybe". I like your modesty. This link contains more information than I could ever hope to get here. 10/10 Matt.

Comment: Use a simple flag to signal the task to stop and then stop it programmatically. Something in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62647874/12323248) direction.

Answer (score 6):

A `CompletableFuture` is an object encapsulating one of three state:

1. Not completed,
2. Completed with a value, or
3. Completed exceptionally

The transition from “Not completed” to one of the other states can be triggered by a function passed to one of its factory methods or to one of the `CompletionStage` implementation methods.

But it’s also possible to invoke `complete` or `completeExceptionally` on it. In that regard, calling `cancel` on it has the same effect as calling `completeExceptionally(new CancellationException())` on it.

That’s also what its class name suggests, it’s a future that *can* be completed rather than *will [eventually] be* completed. The class does not offer control over the existing completion attempts that may run in arbitrary threads and it doesn’t treat the completion attempts scheduled by itself specially.

It’s also important to understand that when chaining operations via the `CompletionStage` implementation methods, the resulting future only represents the last stage of the chain and cancelling it also can only affect the last stage.

E.g. the following code

```java
CompletableFuture<?> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        String s = "value1";
        System.out.println("return initial " + s);
        return s;
    }).thenApply(s -> {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("return transformed " + s);
        return s;
    }).thenAccept(s -> {
        System.out.println("starting last stage");
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        System.out.println("processed " + s);
    });
cf.cancel(false);
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

will print

```
return initial value1
return transformed VALUE1
```

demonstrating that only the last stage of the chain has been cancelled whereas the preceding stage ran to completion, entirely unaffected.

Keeping a reference to the first stage in an attempt to cancel the entire chain would only work as long as the first stage has not completed, as an attempt to cancel an already completed future has no effect.

```java
long[] waitBeforeCancel = { 500, 1500 };
for(long l: waitBeforeCancel) {
    CompletableFuture<String> first = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        String s = "value1";
        System.out.println("return initial " + s);
        return s;
    });
    first.thenApply(s -> {
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
            s = s.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("return transformed " + s);
            return s;
        }).thenAccept(s -> {
            System.out.println("starting last stage");
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
            System.out.println("processed " + s);
        });
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(l));
    System.out.println("Trying to cancel");
    first.cancel(false);
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println();
}
```

```
Trying to cancel
return initial value1

return initial value1
Trying to cancel
return transformed VALUE1
starting last stage
processed VALUE1
```

This demonstrates that the entire chain gets cancelled when the first stage is cancelled in time (except that the `Supplier`’s code of the first still completes due to the nonexistent interruption), whereas cancelling too late will not affect any stage.

Remembering all `CompletableFuture` instances, to be able to cancel all of them, would defeat the purpose of the API. You can use an executor that tracks all currently processed jobs, to forward cancellation and interruption to them when the last stage has been cancelled. The `CompletableFuture` implementation will forward the cancellation to dependent stages then. That way, completed stages still can be garbage collected.

The setup is a bit involved; the wrapper executor is needed before-hand to construct the `CompletableFuture` chain and the forwarding of the cancellation needs the last stage of the already constructed chain. That’s why I made a utility method accepting the chain construction code as a `Function<Executor,CompletableFuture<T>>`:

```java
static <T> Future<T> setupForInterruption(Function<Executor,CompletableFuture<T>> f) {
    return setupForInterruption(f, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
}
static <T> Future<T> setupForInterruption(
        Function<Executor,CompletableFuture<T>> f, Executor e) {

    AtomicBoolean dontAcceptMore = new AtomicBoolean();
    Set<Future<?>> running = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    Executor wrapper = r -> {
        if(dontAcceptMore.get()) throw new CancellationException();
        FutureTask<?> ft = new FutureTask<>(r, null) {
            @Override protected void done() { running.remove(this); }
        };
        running.add(ft);
        e.execute(ft);
    };
    CompletableFuture<T> cf = f.apply(wrapper);
    cf.whenComplete((v,t) -> {
        if(cf.isCancelled()) {
            dontAcceptMore.set(true);
            running.removeIf(ft -> ft.cancel(true) || ft.isDone());
        }
    });
    return cf;
}
```

This can be used like

```java
long[] waitBeforeCancel = { 500, 1500, 2500, 3500 };
for(long l: waitBeforeCancel) {
    Future<?> f = setupForInterruption(executor ->
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
                if(Thread.interrupted()) throw new IllegalStateException();
                String s = "value1";
                System.out.println("return initial " + s);
                return s;
            }, executor).thenApplyAsync(s -> {
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
                if(Thread.interrupted()) throw new IllegalStateException();
                s = s.toUpperCase();
                System.out.println("return transformed " + s);
                return s;
            }, executor).thenAcceptAsync(s -> {
                System.out.println("starting last stage");
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
                if(Thread.interrupted()) throw new IllegalStateException();
                System.out.println("processed " + s);
            }, executor));
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(l));
    System.out.println("Trying to cancel");
    f.cancel(true);
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println();
}
```

```
Trying to cancel

return initial value1
Trying to cancel

return initial value1
return transformed VALUE1
starting last stage
Trying to cancel

return initial value1
return transformed VALUE1
starting last stage
processed VALUE1
Trying to cancel
```

Since the API uses `Supplier`, `Function`, and `Consumer`, none of them being allowed to throw `InterruptedException`, this example code bears explicit test for interruption and throws `IllegalStateException` instead. That’s also the reason it uses `parkNanos` which just immediately returns on interruption instead of `Thread.sleep` in the first place. In real application scenarios, you’ll likely call interruption sensitive methods and have to catch `InterruptedException`, `InterruptedIOException`, or `InterruptedNamingException` (etc.) and convert them to an unchecked exception.

Note that above methods will always cancel with interruption, as the `CompletableFuture` does not tell whether the cancellation was with interruption or not. If you want to get the value of this parameter, you need a front-end `Future` implementation that reflects the result of the last stage, forwards cancellation to it, but passes the value of the `mayInterruptIfRunning` to the currently running jobs.

```java
class FrontEnd<R> implements Future<R> {
    final CompletableFuture<R> lastStage;
    final Set<Future<?>> running;

    FrontEnd(CompletableFuture<R> lastStage, Set<Future<?>> running) {
        this.lastStage = lastStage;
        this.running = running;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        boolean didCancel = lastStage.cancel(false);
        if(didCancel)
            running.removeIf(f -> f.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning) || f.isDone());
        return didCancel;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return lastStage.isCancelled();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        return lastStage.isDone();
    }
    @Override
    public R get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return lastStage.get();
    }
    @Override
    public R get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {

        return lastStage.get(timeout, unit);
    }

    static <T> Future<T> setup(Function<Executor,CompletableFuture<T>> f) {
        return setup(f, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
    }
    static <T> Future<T> setup(Function<Executor,CompletableFuture<T>> f, Executor e) {
        AtomicBoolean dontAcceptMore = new AtomicBoolean();
        Set<Future<?>> running = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        Executor wrapper = r -> {
            if(dontAcceptMore.get()) throw new CancellationException();
            FutureTask<?> ft = new FutureTask<>(r, null) {
                @Override protected void done() { running.remove(this); }
            };
            running.add(ft);
            e.execute(ft);
        };
        CompletableFuture<T> cf = f.apply(wrapper);
        cf.whenComplete((v,t) -> { if(cf.isCancelled()) dontAcceptMore.set(true); });
        return new FrontEnd<>(cf, running);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine a `CompletableFuture` to be just a (typed) handle to an async subprocess (of course it has some more benefits). But it is NOT a controller of the async subprocess. You not even have a direct access to it (or the thread executing it).

To implement an `abort()` I did it this way, extending the `CompletableFuture`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import x.y.MyEnum;

/**
 * Provides an interruptible CompletableFuture implementation for one time usage.
 */
public final class InteruptibleCompletableFuture extends CompletableFuture<MyEnum>
{
    /**
     * the embedded executor service
     */
    private ExecutorService myExecutorService;
    
    /**
     * Executes the given supplier asynchronously and returns the future to wait for.
     * 
     * @param aSupplier the supplier to be executed
     * @return the CompletableFuture to wait for
     */
    public static InteruptibleCompletableFuture execute(Supplier<MyEnum> aSupplier)
    {
        InteruptibleCompletableFuture result = new InteruptibleCompletableFuture();
        
        result.myExecutorService.submit( () -> 
        {
            try
            {
                MyEnum res = aSupplier.get(); 
                result.complete( res);
            }
            catch ( Throwable ex )
            {
                result.completeExceptionally( ex);
            }
        });
    
        return result;
    }

    private InteruptibleCompletableFuture()
    {
        super();
        myExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean complete( MyEnum value)
    {
        if ( isDone() )
        {
            // Future already completed
            return false;
        }
        
        shutdownExecutorService();
        return super.complete( value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean completeExceptionally( Throwable ex)
    {
        if ( isDone() )
        {
            // Future already completed
            return false;
        }
        
        shutdownExecutorService();
        return super.completeExceptionally( ex);
    }
    
    private void shutdownExecutorService()
    {
        try
        {
            myExecutorService.shutdownNow();
        }
        catch ( Throwable e )
        {
            // log error
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that this implementation has a hand on the executor. Forcing a termination from the main application delegates to the call `myExecutorService.shutdownNow()`. Read the javadoc of this method carefully.

Be aware that java has no legal method to *kill* a thread. A call to myThread.interrupt() does not kill it. It just sets the interrupted flag and wakes up the thread if it was waiting in a monitor (throwing an InterruptedException). Your implementation *must* check the interrupted flag regularly if it is doing a batch job in a loop, and also react correctly to an InterruptedException.

Comment: `ExecutorService`s are robust to interrupts and shutting it down for each task defeats the purpose of it. You can achieve the same effect by simply creating a `Thread` and calling interrupt directly. Which is a lot of overhead anyway. But none of it addresses my question with `Future.cancel(boolean)`. Matt's answer on the other hand does, because `Promise` class provides this functionality